# Using Python to sort text file

Tags: python, file, sorting, text

Ok I have a text file presented like this:

```
Data1A
Data1B

Data2A
Data2B
```

There is no space between Data 1A and 1B, and 2A and 2B, there is a space though, between 1 and 2.

Is it possible to use Python to read this text file, and arrange the data like this

```
Data1A Data1B
Data2A Data2B
```

preferably I would like to read it, sort it and export it in CSV format, however, even just sorting it so data sections A and B are side by side would be a big help.

If it is do-able, could you help me in finding sufficient tutorials or something to achieve it?

Comment: Are the HTML tags part of your input? Hint: Please indent code with four spaces,

Comment: How big is this file, roughly? It's important to know because sometimes it's easy to read the whole file to memory and process it. But if it's huge it's not feasible and you have to come up with something more clever.

Comment: Broadly speaking, I'd probably do it like this: read the file into a string. Call `split("\n\n")` to separate the Data1 section from the Data2 section. Iterate through each section, `split("\n")` to get a collection of lines, `sort` them, and `" ".join` the lines back up so they're all one one line as desired. Then you're ready to write them back to the file.

Comment: [Here](https://docs.python.org/2/library/csv.html) is the Python documentation on the CSV module.

Comment: I believe file size will be an issue, daily logs are giving me 15MB of data, with maybe monthly logs being stripped (465MB)

Comment: No, 465MB is not an issue, unless your hard drive is out of space.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming this is written in the file `in.txt`:

```
with open("fin.txt","r") as fin:
    a=[]
    for line in fin:
         a.append(line)
b=sorted(a)
aSorted=[[b[i+1][:-1] for i in range(len(b)-1)] ]
```

This would give you a sorted list, no matter in what order the inputs are read. There are several ways to output your data. Depends on how general you want the code to be. One very simple option would be:

```
with open("fou.csv","w") as fou:
    for i in range(len(aSorted)//2):
         fou.write("%s,\t%s\n" % (aSorted[0+i],aSorted[1+i]))
```

Comment: Now that Andrejs Cainikovs editted it, I saw that there is one blank line. That wasn't there in the original version of the question. Just editted my code to take that into consideration.

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at `itertools.groupby`:

```
import itertools as it

with open(fn_in, 'r') as fi, open(fn_out, 'w') as fo:
    for b, lines in it.groupby(fi, key=str.strip):
        if b:
            fo.write(' '.join(line.strip() for line in lines) + '\n')
```

This works even for large files since it works sequentially line after line.

It groups lines according to the result of `str.strip` (newline-stripped line), which is `b = True` for not-empty lines and `b = False` for empty lines. In `lines` you get a generator of lines belonging to the group. Ignore the `b = False`, which is usually a single separator empty line and join the `lines` for `b = True`.

Answer (score 0):

Well, assuming that the file is not too large and it can be read inmemory, the following code would do the job:-

```
import re
reference_dict = {}
with open("input", "r") as f:
    for line in f.readlines():
        line = line.strip('\n')
        regex = re.compile("^Data(?P<row>[0-9]*).*$")
        search_result = regex.search(line)
        if search_result:
            row = search_result.groupdict()['row']
            if row in reference_dict:
                reference_dict[row].append(line)
            else:
                reference_dict[row] = [line]

print reference_dict  #prints {'1': ['Data1A', 'Data1B'], '2': ['Data2A', 'Data2B']}
```

You have the grouping as needed. It can be used in whatever way you need. The code is self explanatory. Please comment if you need more explanation?